# Relativity of simultaneity with 2 observers on platform

Tags: special-relativity

Reading Harris' *Modern Physics*, specifically the classic example of Anna holding two lightbulbs on a moving train. I find myself confused about this passage:

> Before moving on, we emphasize a vital point: The preceding arguments
> had nothing at all to do with Bob's specific location in his frame or the time it
> takes light to reach his eyes. The issue here is not which beam reaches Bob
> first, which does depend on where he stands, but rather which begins first,
> which has nothing to do with where he stands. Attempting to blame the effect
> on optical illusions is the comfortable yet incorrect way out of accepting a
> counterintuitive notion. The truth is more challenging. Bob could be standing
> right next to one flashbulb when it flashes and have an assistant, Bob Jr.,
> standing next to the other flashbulb when it flashes. Each records the time of
> his flash and neither has to wait for the light to reach his eyes. They record different times. Anna, in her frame, causes the bulbs to flash simultaneously, but
> Bob and Bob Jr., from their frame, determine that she causes the bulbs to flash
> at different times.

I guess my understanding of the relativity of simultaneity was dependent on thinking about the path that light took to travel to Bob. If Bob/Bob Jr can be right next to the lightbulb, I am failing to see how that's any different then them being on the train with Anna.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point being made is that the relativity of simultaneity is not an illusion based on how long it takes light to reach an observer. Suppose Anna has a bulb at each end of her moving train, and she causes them to flash at the same instant in the frame of the train. Now suppose there was a line of observers all along the platform. An observer standing right next to the front of the passing train sees the front light flash and notes the time, as does an observer standing right alongside the rear light as it passes. When they compare notes, they will see that the observer next to the rear light saw it flash before the other observer saw the front light flash, even though each observer was the same distance from the flash they saw. When you express it that way, you rule out possible misunderstandings about the nature of the relativity of simultaneity.

Comment: Right - I think I understood that was what the passage was saying, but I'm having trouble justifying it. Is it just that: if the two observers on the platform recorded the same time, then the lights must have reached Anna at different times (bc she is moving), which breaks Postulate #1?

Comment: @linkedin yes, if you assume the light from the flashes meet at the centre of the train, then they must have been simultaneous in the frame of the train. On the other hand, since, at the instant the flashes meet, the centre of the train is not midway between the two observers on the platform  but nearer the front observer than the rear, the front glass must have been later than the rear flash in the frame of the platform.